# Should the seed of CSPRNG produce the same random number?

Tags: random-number-generator

Assume we are designing a CSPRNG to be used in encryption like that used for ECC-based cryptography.

Is it required that the seed always produces the same random number always? Or should it be  designed to produce different numbers, making it even more secure?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE! I guess that you are trying to ask: _if given the same seed, should a CSPRNG always produce the same numbers; or would designing it to produce differents numbers make it even more secure?_ This [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76521/555) assumes such reading of the question.

Comment: Note that there is CSPRNG in the title and CSRNG (without the P for pseudo) in the body of the question. May we assume CSPRNG also for the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seed is the source of entropy for any CSPRNG. A CSPRNG is a *pseudo* random number generator. The "pseudo" part in the name explicitly means that it solely depends on entropy delivered from outside the algorithm using one or more seeds. So a CSPRNG, by definition, **cannot** be designed to produce "different numbers", as the outcome *solely* depends on the seeding of the algorithm.

Maybe the term "deterministic random bit generator" or DRBG better catches this meaning - most CSPRNG implementations do also *primarily* output pseudo-random bits rather than pseudo-random (ranged) numbers.

---

Now CSPRNG **implementations** in many runtimes depend on seeding by the operating system. Such seeding may even take place if a user provides a seed themselves. Basically such systems treat the seed as an **additional** source of entropy, making the next retrieved values depend on *both* the entropy sources, by mixing them into the state.

Furthermore, CSPRNG algorithms or algorithm implementations may be configured (explicitly or implicitly) to perform *re-seeding* after a certain amount of bits or calls. In that case the CSPRNG performs a callback to the system that provides the (initial) seed to retrieve additional seeds, which are then mixed into the state. A user may usually also call a method to add seeds or fire a request to re-seeding.

Often CSPRNG's are not explicitly required to return the same random bits if the amount of bits are different between calls. Even if the CSPRNG is in the same state, asking for 8 bits and then 16 bits may result in different values than asking for 16 bits and then 8 bits.

CSPRNG's may also change their implementation slightly, for instance they may generate numbers in a range using several different methods.

All this makes using a CSPRNG of a runtime system very dangerous if you expect to having it generate the same sequence for the same seed, and using a CSPRNG for such purposes it a huge red flag within any design - unless the CSPRNG is *explicitly designed* for such purpose.

---

If you do need a predictable stream then you are better off using a KDF (for relatively small output), a XOF such as SHAKE-128 or SHAKE-256 or indeed a stream cipher. Beware though that crypto-systems such as EC may also use the bits in different ways, so if *those* systems change implementation, you'd still get different results.

Generally, however, a well seeded CSPRNG is all you need to implement a cryptosystem that requires randomness.

Answer (score 2):

The term "CSPRNG" is one that I find less than entirely helpful, because it tends to encompass two distinct types of algorithm:

- Algorithms designed to output reproducible pseudorandom streams—meaning that a sender and a receiver that have a shared secret can both independently produce the same output. The term **stream cipher** is often used to label such algorithms—confusingly, since it also names the concept of encrypting messages by XORing them with the output of such an algorithm.
- Algorithms designed to serve as practical substitutes for true random number sources, in which reproducibility is not a requirement. These are typically found in operating system kernels, and in addition to cryptographic pseudorandomness, have mechanisms that sample hardware events (e.g., network interface timings) to randomize their output.

Another way to look at this is to consider the following three properties:

1. **Strong pseudorandomness:** An adversary who can't see or guess the generator's internal state cannot (in practice) predict its output.
2. **Backtracking resistance:** An adversary who sees the internal state at one point in time cannot (in practice) work backwards to reconstruct earlier outputs. (A.k.a. *forward secrecy*).
3. **Prediction resistance:** If an adversary sees the internal state of the generator at one point in time, there's only a limited window of time during which they can predict its future outputs.

Some applications (e.g., stream cipher encryption) only need the strong pseudorandomness. Others, like generation of long-term secret keys, definitely want forward secrecy—you don't want the disclosure of one key to allow the adversary to figure out earlier ones, for example.

Note the third property, prediction resistance, requires that the generator produce results that are not fully determined by its internal state. This is implemented as I mentioned before—by sampling random data, typically from hardware devices, and using it as an additional input to a core deterministic pseudorandom algorithm.

So the answer to your question is both yes and no, in a sense. Practical pseudorandom generators are often designed to produce different numbers in response to equivalent client calls, because this improves security in **some** scenarios. But this isn't necessary or appropriate for all applications where we want pseudorandom bits—it all hinges on context.

Answer (score 1):

Since its a "Cryptographically Secure" PRNG it should produce a random number every time given some input, ideally a source of entropy which acts as the "seed". Given the same input, the algorithm should produce the same value every time, but when designing a CSPRNG the input should be different every time and come from a source of entropy.

Comment: But why should "Given the same input, the algorithm should produce the same value every time" What happens if it didn't?

Comment: @Tararu: in CSPRNG, the P stands for Pseudo. That often is undserstood as meaning: _Given the same input, the generator produces the same output every time_. Among reasons to do this in practice: it allows testing of implementation; that's useful in some applications (such as, generating an RSA key pair from a 256-bit key). When needing truly random numbers of cryptographic quality, one option is to feed a CSPRNG with a truly random seed. There are more complex TRNGs, with e.g. the goal that knowledge of previous state does not allow to predict future output.

Comment: "the entropy should be different every time" this statement makes no sense.

Comment: Right, I wasn't very clear in my original answer. I'll edit, but what I meant was "the input should be different every time."